# Не исключаются файлы из репозитория git на удаленном сервере

Tags: git, git-commit, gitignore

Были обнаружены лишние файлы на боевом сервере. Допустим с расширением `*.txt`. С помощью `git rm --cached *.txt` файлы удалены с разрабатываемого сервера, commit, push, далее pull на боевом сервере. Ок, файлы пропали.

Далее в `.git/info/exclude` добавляем строку `*.txt`
запускал команду и `git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude` и пытался `git update-index --assume-unchanged *.txt`

Также создавал файл `.gitexcludes` со стройкой `*.txt` и выполнением команды `git config core.excludesfile .gitexcludes`

Все это не помогает. В репозитории нужны файлы `*.txt`, а на боевом сервере не нужны. Но как только возвращаем файлы в репозиторий, то с первым же коммитом они прилетают обратно на боевой сервер...

Как мне в итоге правильно удалить файлы с боевого сервера, игнорировать их в дальнейшем на боевом сервере, но оставить в репозитории?

Comment: В общем почитал документацию подробнее (на сайте https://docs.github.com/en) про исключения. Видимо excludefile работает только глобально, хотя четкого указания на это в документации не увидел. Я умышленно исключил ключ `--global`, чтобы было для одного проекта, но так не работает. Правильная, команда такая: `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global` ... в этом случае все работает, как мне нужно, но для всего сервера, что от части подходит для решения проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант №1

Вынести все эти файлы в сабмодуль, и вычитывать его только на рабочей копии, а на боевом сервере - нет.

Вариант №2

Сделать релизную ветку, в которой удалены эти файлы. На боевом сервере разворачивать из нее, а не из master'а

Comment: Как Вы указали, скорее всего, тоже вариант, но почему у меня не работает gitignore gitexclude? Может какой индекс надо обновить или кеш сбросить, о котором я ничего не знаю... Должны же нормально работать исключения локальные.

Comment: @Firsov36 нужно не гит мучить, а просто сделать нормальный деплой. деплой через git - это ещё то удовольствие. Сломают сервер и папка .git расскажет о Вашем проекте много чего. Самый простой способ - пишите скрипт, который с гита вытянет свежую/правильную версию, поправит файлы (добавит/поудаляет), потрогает конфиги и упакует в архив. И уже архив на сервере распаковывать. Как "побочный эффект" - легко сделать откат на предыдущую версию.

Comment: @KoVadim мощно! Но это не мой случай для данного проекта.

Comment: В общем почитал документацию подробнее (на сайте https://docs.github.com/en) про исключения. Видимо excludefile работает только глобально, хотя четкого указания на это в документации не увидел. Я умышленно исключил ключ `--global`, чтобы было для одного проекта, но так не работает. Правильная, команда такая: `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global` ... в этом случае все работает, как мне нужно, но для всего сервера, что от части подходит для решения проблемы.